# Убрать заголовок окна Chromium при запуске --app=

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium

Сейчас такой набор флагов

'--window-size=800,600', '--ash-host-window-bounds=800x600', '--window-position=200,200', '--disable-experimental-fullscreen-exit-ui', '--app=http://localhost:3001/?hid=2', '--disable-site-isolation-trials', '--disable-web-security', '--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required', '--load-extension=./extensions/noxframe,./extensions/allowcors./extensions/noblank,/mnt/data/Projects/2021/yar2/fsline/extensions/screensaver,./extensions/keyboard', '--disable-infobars'

Но окошко открывается с заголовком и кнопками _ [] X

Как убрать декорацию у окна?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть `--kiosk`?

Comment: @donRumata полный экран, а нужно в окне

Comment: Я не понял, если честно. Можешь скрин кинуть чё ты хочешь убрать\добавить? Схематически.

Comment: @donRumata прикрепил картинку

Comment: Оно? https://www.simplified.guide/google-chrome/chromium-hide-system-title-bar

Comment: @donRumata неа, если вернуть адресную строку - стиль без системного бара. не тот флаг

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное что нашел - подсунуть background.js через упаковку в приложение.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/apps/samples/frameless-window/background.js

Но хром похоже хоронит это апи полностью

> Support for all platforms will end in June 2022.